# What is the easiest way to convert csv file into inputs for machine learning?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, tensorflow, machine-learning

I know you can do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('mushrooms.csv')
df.apply(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0])
```

but what I want is to change all categories to be `0` or `1`.

An example would be if the headers in the CSV file are `favColor` and `favCookie`, and the options for `favColor` are 'red', 'orange' and 'green', and the options for `favCookie` are 'chocolate' and 'sugar'. If one of the rows is 'red' and 'sugar', I would want the full row to change into `[1,0,0,0,1]`.

I was looking more for like a library so it will be easy doing this every time I use a CSV file and a neural network

Answer (score 3):

With `pandas`, you can just use `pandas.get_dummies()`:

```
new_df = pd.get_dummies(df)
```

If you want to use `scikit-learn`, you can use the `OneHotEncoder`:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

new_np_array = OneHotEncoder().fit_transform(df.values)
```

As I indicated with the variable names, `get_dummies()` returns a `pandas` dataframe, whereas `OneHotEncoder` returns a `numpy` array

Answer (score 0):

## Importing CSV file in Tensorflow

### Use new Dataset API(released as part of TF 1.4 version) to Speed up entire process

**Step for reading from CSV Files:**

1) Read the CSV file name 
2) Create TextLineDataset by providing the CSV file name
3) Create the Parse function for decoding and do any preprocessing work in input data
4) Create batching, repeat(no of epoch) and shuffling using dataset created in previous steps
5) Create the Iterator to fetch required inputs as a batch(i.e. mini-batch)

Eg code:

```
from matplotlib.image import imread
def input_model_function():
    csv_filename =['images.csv']
    dataset = tf.data.TextLineDataset(csv_filename)
    dataset = dataset.map(_parse_function)
    dataset = dataset.batch(20)# you can use any number of batching
    iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
    sess = tf.Session()
    batch_images, batch_labels = sess.run(iterator.get_next())
return {'x':batch_images}, batch_labels

def _parse_function(line):
    image, labels= tf.decode_csv(line,record_defaults=[[""], [0]])
    # Decode the raw bytes so it becomes a tensor with type.
    image = imread(image)# give full path name of image
return image, labels
```

Finally input batched Dataset into Model(created using any Pre-Made Estimator or Custom Estimator API)